# Why do some camcorders record in 1080i?

Tags: full-hd

Why do some camcorders record in 1080i? Does it have any technical or visual advantages over 1080p?

Let's suppose that all media players and TVs which can handle 1080i can also handle 1080p. Is there still an advantage of 1080i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses a lower data rate (within the TV, not for the actual signal) and is cheaper to produce.  That is all.  The only difference is that if you are going to view it on a 1080i display, then shooting in 1080i would look slightly smoother since half the information updates every half a frame rather than updating the whole thing at once, but 1080p is preferable pretty much hands down on a 1080p display.

Interlacing just means that the upper and then lower fields update alternately.  It's less difficult to fake interlacing than it is to deinterlace, but you still get some artifacts displaying a progressive scan image on an interlaced display because of how things update.

Comment: There are no interlaced displays anymore, though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - maybe no new ones, but there are still 1080i displays that don't support 1080p hanging around.  I have one in my bedroom.

Comment: Don't forget that many broadcast stations (air waves vs. cable or satellite) broadcast in 1080i.

Comment: @AJHenderson - Why is the 'lower data rate' claim?

Comment: @Izhaki - within the display it is a lower data rate as only half the screen has to be refreshed at a time.  Each field is only half the information, and while there is still twice as many fields as frames, each field only has to update 30 times a second.  Thus, the TV only has to have half the data rate for each field (but the total between the fields is the same).  This matters for loading in to the frame buffers that control the display.

Comment: Oh... OK.... The last sentence gives the real explanation. One can easily misinterpret your answer to think that interlaced has altogether lower data rate than progressive. As you mentioned, both involve the same amount of data (only with interlaced a frame is split into 2 fields).

Comment: @Izhaki - agreed, I updated the answer to make it more clear.